# status update on facebook without dialog Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using facebook-android-sdk-3.5.2, I want to post a message on facebook wall by clicking on button without showing dialog, I have tried many codes, some are saying "to post without dialog use Graph Api" but I don't understand how to use graph api. Some hav also given this solution which not work with me and not showing any error.

```
                    String message = "weLcom3";
                Bundle parameterss = new Bundle();
                parameterss.putString("message", message);
        try {
            fb.request("feed", parameterss, "POST");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: please help me, if some one can. please dear i m wait

Comment: any link, help, tutorial please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", parameterss, 
            HttpMethod.POST, checkincallback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();

    Request.Callback checkincallback = new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                // error
            } else {
                //succeeded
            }
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: dear! can u help me if give me a complete simple example code with main.java and main.xml with 1 button to share a message on facebook. i am working on it from last 2 days but i failed to get it. i really stucked in it. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may help you, I am able to post without dialog box to facebook by this

```
String response;
        try {
            String msg="your message to be posted";
            response = facebook.request("me");
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("message",msg);
            b.putString("description", "Test test test");
            response=facebook.request("me/feed",b, "Post");
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) 
            {
               System.out.println("Blank Response");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```